# Why I am getting error on flask-mysql installing in linux

Tags: python, mysql

I am getting this error Please help me....

```
Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Successfully built flask-mysqldb
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: click, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, Werkzeug, itsdangerous, Flask, mysqlclient, flask-mysqldb
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-0cvtg8k7/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-d77uypia-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,4,6,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.6 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -latomic -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-0cvtg8k7/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-d77uypia-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-0cvtg8k7/mysqlclient/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's missing a package or header file. Try installing libssl-dev package.

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Comment: I am getting this ..
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-dev is already the newest version (3.6.7-1~18.04).
python3-dev set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Thanks Bro !! You just saved me. Please suggest me any easy and best tutorial for flask